# Laravel 6: disable all routes for guest except home and login

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I need to disable all routes for guests in Laravel except '/' and 'login' pages.

Does that possible to implement it routes/web.php ?

Comment: Yes, you can add a middleware for that and assign it to your route group: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In your `routes/web.php` file, make sure to define your protected routes under the `auth` middleware group.

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    // / route
});

Route::get('/login', function() {
    // login page
});

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    // define your routes here
    // they'll be protected
});
```

[Official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)

Comment: I thought we can apply something like mask: !['/login', '/']  :(

Comment: This is a way illustrated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 7.7 you can use `excluded_middleware` property eg:

```php
Route::group([
    'excluded_middleware' => ['auth'],
], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    
...
});
```